# Can I connect an object to more IBActions in iOS?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, xib, ibaction

Say I have a button that, when tapped, should perform two actions:

```
func firstFunction() {
    ...
}

func secondFunction() {
    ...
}
```

I know that I can connect an object to one action. Though it doesn't seem like I can connect it to more than one. I tried dragging and dropping the plus circle (please see image) but it doesn't seem to connect to the `secondFunction()`.

Functions shouldn't have side effects. Say, for instance, that I want to call `firstFunction` from somewhere in my code, but not `secondFunction`.

Can I connect an object to more `IBAction`s in iOS?

[image]

Comment: I am sorry but this makes absolutly no sense. If you want to perform both actions, just call action 2 in action 1.

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff functions shouldn't have side effects. Say I want to call `firstFunction` from somewhere in my code, but not `secondFunction`. What do you think?

Comment: No, I guess we can't. it can only be done by calling the 2 action in 1st action

Comment: Logics can be made though, but connections can't be multiple in your case

Comment: Then you call thridFunction from your action, which calls firstFunction and then secondFunction....

Comment: If you want to perform both action every time then there is no point of keeping two action just marge both and keep one.but if you want to perform some action depend on the event type like for UIButton there are touch up inside ,touch up outside etc. then you can drag and use no issue on that.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari iOS supports multiple action connections from a single sender.

Comment: @robmayoff Great. I haven't experienced that. Thanks a lot. Can you tell me in which order these actions are called if we connect two actions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. In iOS, most (all?) objects that use the target/action paradigm support multiple targets and actions.  Just control-drag from the sender (or a specific sent event of the sender) to each action, one at a time:

[image: Xcode demo]

Comment: @robmayoff Great. I haven't experienced that. Thanks a lot. Can you tell me in which order these actions are called if we connect two actions. Also is it advisable to do that?

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari I just checked: the first action you connect will execute first. Consequently, all the functions will be called in the order they were connected.